# Having issues with implementing Serial code outside of the PyQt GUI loop? (Reading serial)?

Tags: python, events, pyqt, serial-port

I am trying to make a program with PyQt (mostly for my own practice)  that will listen to the Serial port and read out any stream of data.

I have been using Tkinter for some time, but PyQt5 is quite a different beast.

I am having issues with having a loop that will recognize if the serial port has any messages in the buffer, and then updating the GUI accordingly, because the Serial issue is not a GUI event so to speak.

I have tried solving this by having a separate thread that would check if there is something on the serial port, however it seems like I get an error that tells me that I can't update the GUI with a function on a separate thread.

https://pastebin.com/HK1Frh5g

```
    def find_port(self):
    if self.is_connected is False:
        self.is_connected = True
    else:
        self.is_connected = False
    for port in serial.tools.list_ports.comports():
        if port.vid == 5824 and port.pid == 1155:
            self.ser.port = str(port.device)
            self.port_found = True
            print("Found")
    if self.port_found is False:
        print("Not found")
    x = threading.Thread(target=self.talk_module)
    x.start()

def talk_module(self):
    self.ser.open()
    while self.is_connected is True:
        fd_line = self.ser.readline().decode()
        print(fd_line)
        self.table_widget.add_row(fd_line)
    self.ser.close()
```

Here is a link to my code so far.  Also is a snippet that shows the threading.  The function works, I just can't get it to update the GUI

Basically, I would like to be able to press a button or a dialog and have the serial port be read from until I press another button.

With Tkinter, I was able to update the GUI with a method, and have stuff happen in my own functions.

PyQt seems different, and I was wondering if i could find some guidance.  Thanks !

Comment: I haven't used PyQt before, but at least in normal Qt you would create a `QSerialPort` object and connect to the `readyRead` signal.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55070483/connect-to-serial-from-a-pyqt-gui

Comment: @rm5248 hey, thanks for the reply!  This does look like a solution.  I will test it out asap.  I did however also figure out how to do it with my implementation.  It seems like I had to create a new signal and that is able to "signal" between threads.  Actually works really nicely!  Will update my question with my own answer soon