# serial port blocks GUI - emitting signal blocks PyQt-App

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyserial

I have an PyQt5 application where a pushbutton triggers communication with a serial device. While the application is running, it also grabs images from a camera. However, when the serial communication is busy with reading/writing the GUI does not update and the images from the camera are not show.

I've tried to solve the problem by having 3 separate threads - 1: GUI, 2: serial comm, 3: image grab. Communication between them is done by Signals. Unfortunately, when I signal the 2nd thread to do the communication, the 1st thread (GUI) does not update.

The layout looks basically like that:

```
Thread1 = GUI:
    signal to Thread2, when serial comm requested
    slot for Thread3, for image data grabbed from device

Thread2 = Serial comm:
    slot for Thread1, for data to be send via serial port

Thread3 = Image grab:
    signal to Thread1, when new image data is available
```

So, when I need something to be sent via serial port, Thread1 emits a signal to Thread2 and then should continue to do its message loop, e.g. reacting on signals from Thread3 and draw the new image. The signal to Thread2 seems to block until everything is done in serial comm Thread.

The slot in Thread2 looks like that:

```
@pyqtSlot(int, int, int)
def motor_move(self, motor, direction, steps):
    """
    Move motor one step in given direction.

    Parameters
    ----------
    motor : int
        Motor index.
    direction : int
        Direction.

    Returns
    -------
    None.

    """

    if self._motor.serial_port:
       self._motor.motor_move(motor, steps, direction) # here the serial communication happens
```

Now the questions:
How to unblock the GUI while the serial port is busy?
Can I send some return value that indicates that the signal has been handled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the connection type between the emitted signal and the slot.

Previously I used:

```
.connect(self._move_thread.motor_move)
```

When emitting the signal PyQt5 determines what type of connection should by established. And in this case always decided to go for a `Qt.DirectConnection` which runs the slot immediately but waits (!) until the slot returns. This is shown in the output:

```
Arduino got: " " # what I have sent
0.0 5.0 # slot takes 5 seconds to return
Done # this is the signaling thread continuing after the slot returns
```

Using:

```
.connect(self._move_thread.motor_move, , type=Qt.QueuedConnection)
```

The processing of the slot is queued in the EventLoop and the signaling thread is not waiting for the slot to return. The output is now:

```
Arduino got: " " # what I have sent
Done # this is the signaling thread continuing immediately after emitting the signal
0.0 5.0 # slot takes 5 seconds to return
```

Comment: Why don't you use QSerialPort and thus avoid threads problems? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55070483/connect-to-serial-from-a-pyqt-gui/55071476#55071476

Comment: Didn't know these. But they won't solve the problem that my serial device is slow in its response and hence blocks my app when not put in a separate thread.

Comment: Your device can be slow or fast but the advantage of QSerialPort is that it uses signals to obtain the data avoiding adding unnecessary complexity. Unlike with pyserial you wait if there is data instead QSerialPort you connect a function that will be invoked when there is hardly any data.

Comment: I've tried QSerialPort. The GUI still freezes for a short moment, but overall the integration works better. I can live with the current way. Thanks for the advice.