# PyQTSerial vs PUTTY : I get different results : WHY?

Tags: pyqt, putty

I am trying to get the same results with python code than I get in putty :
I am using PyQT from this thread [Connect to serial from a PyQt GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55070483/connect-to-serial-from-a-pyqt-gui)

=> when I start the serial connection, I am supposed to receive first messages from the serial connection (intrudtcion, ex "type help to get the list of commands").
I get it in PUTTY but not in python.
Why ?
How should I do to get it in python ?

PS context : I am trying to establish a connection with a command card I received from a subcontractor. I used to command it through putty and I want to change for python, but I do not manage to send and received the same commands than with putty ( I though it was simple...)

I tried this :

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtSerialPort

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.message_le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.send_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
            text="Send",
            clicked=self.send
        )
        self.output_te = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(readOnly=True)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
            text="Connect",
            checkable=True,
            toggled=self.on_toggled
        )
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        hlay.addWidget(self.message_le)
        hlay.addWidget(self.send_btn)
        lay.addLayout(hlay)

        lay.addWidget(self.output_te)
        lay.addWidget(self.button)
        self.serial = QtSerialPort.QSerialPort(
            'COM3',
            baudRate=QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.Baud115200,
            readyRead=self.receive
        )

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def receive(self):
        while self.serial.canReadLine():
            text = self.serial.readLine().data().decode()
            text = text.rstrip('\r\n')
            self.output_te.append(text)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def send(self):
        self.serial.write(self.message_le.text().encode())

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(bool)
    def on_toggled(self, checked):
        self.button.setText("Disconnect" if checked else "Connect")
        if checked:
            if not self.serial.isOpen():
                if not self.serial.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadWrite):
                    self.button.setChecked(False)
        else:
            self.serial.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I expect to receive the first instruction ("type help etc") I usually receive in putty through the "receive" function but I do not receive it.

Comment: Are you sure that that first message ends with an return/new line character?